# agm-marker's markerClick() is returning null

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

From the angular google maps API, we have a markerClick() function with the following definition,

```
 @Output() markerClick: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

But when I am using in my application, I am getting **NULL**.

I have the following code for the application,

In my HTML file,

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom">
        <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of coordinates;" 
        [iconUrl]="icon" 
        [latitude]="marker.latitude" 
        [longitude]="marker.longitude"
        [markerClickable]="true"
        (markerClick)="markerClicked($event)">
    </agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
```

And in .TS file,

```
 markerClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('clicked'); ----------------(1)
    console.log($event);--------------------(2)
  }
```

For statement (2), I am getting NULL as the console output.
I am expecting it to be marker Object. Is my understanding wrong? 
How to get the lat and lng from the markerClick() function.

Note, I am already using ***mapClick()*** function for the **agm-map tag**, but when I am using that function, It is not responding to clicks on already drawn markers on the Map.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look into the [**FILE**](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmMarker.html#source) deeper it always emits `null` :

```
this.markerClick.emit(null); // line no : 192
```

---

What you can do is change this :

```
(markerClick)="markerClicked($event)"
```

To :

```
(markerClick)="markerClicked(marker)" // this way you will get the marker object
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo2)** (Click on any available marker)

Comment: @Anil , please check the WORKING DEMO , https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo2

Comment: Thank You, got the required info, i did not knew, we can pass properties in html.

Comment: @Anil , Glad to know that , Happy Coding BTW :) .

Comment: Is there any way to get the marker object without clicking the marker?

Answer (score 1):

In the app.component.html

```
<agm-map>
<agm-marker  *ngFor="let place of markers" [latitude]=place.lat [longitude]=place.lng  title={{place.title}}  (markerClick)="clickedMarker(place.lat, place.lng)" >
<agm-info-window><strong>{{place.label}}</strong></agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

In the app.components.ts

```
markers: any[] = [];

selectedLat: Number = 0;
selectedLng: Number = 0;

clickedMarker(lat: number, lng: number) {
this.selectedLat = lat;
this.selectedLng = lng;
}
```

Here when the marker is clicked it calls `clickedMarker(lat: number, lng: number)` function. In there selectedLat and selectedLng variables are updated from the sending parameters of the `(markerClick)="clickedMarker(place.lat, place.lng)`

Doesn't use in this way `(markerClick)="markerClicked($event)"`